# Missing class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder (referenced from: void org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind() and 3 other contexts) when using Pusher library

Tags: android, android-build, android-r8

with R8 enabled (`isMinifyEnabled = true`) and using `"com.pusher.pusher-java-client:2.4.4"` library I get the following error for release build:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Missing classes detected while running
> R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that
> are generated in
> project\app\build\outputs\mapping\devRelease\missing_rules.txt.","sources":[{}]}
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Missing class
> org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder (referenced from: void
> org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind() and 3 other
> contexts)","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"} Missing classes detected while
> running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep
> rules that are generated in
> project\app\build\outputs\mapping\devRelease\missing_rules.txt.
>
> Missing class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder (referenced from: void
> org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind() and 3 other contexts)

How can I solve it? With `isMinifyEnabled = false` it builds without issues

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fixed by adding the following rule:

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Pusher Java Client  ----------
-dontwarn org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
##---------------End: proguard configuration for Pusher Java Client  ----------
```